# Pivot longer but associating multiple columns

Tags: r, pivot

I have a data frame of the form:

| A | TCLP_A | B | TCLP_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 10 | 10.1 |
| 2 | 0.2 | 20 | 20.1 |

And want to pivot this longer  to

| Chemcial | Concentration | TCLP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.1 |
| A | 2 | 0.2 |
| B | 10 | 10.1 |
| B | 20 | 20.1 |

I am struggling with the pivot command to achieve it.

```
 df %>% pivot_longer(
    cols = c(!starts_with("TCLP_")), 
    names_to = "Chemical", 
    values_to = "Concentration"
    )
```

gets part way there but I can't work out how to get the TCLP columns pivoted correctly.

I want to pivot the TCLP_A column to be a Chemical with name A but the value in a column called TCLP and matched with the same row in the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can separate the `A` and `B` columns, rename and bind them.

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(
  A = select(df, Concentration = A, TCLP = TCLP_A),
  B = select(df, Concentration = B, TCLP = TCLP_B),
  .id = "Chemical"
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   Chemical Concentration  TCLP
#>   <chr>            <int> <dbl>
#> 1 A                    1   0.1
#> 2 A                    2   0.2
#> 3 B                   10  10.1
#> 4 B                   20  20.1
```

We *can* use `pivot_*()` operations, though the solution above is
more concise.

```r
df |>
  mutate(id = 1:n()) |>
  rename(Concentration_A = A,
         Concentration_B = B) |>
  pivot_longer(-id) |>
  separate(name, c("type", "Chemical"), fill = "left") |>
  replace_na(list(type = "Concentration")) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(type),
              values_from = value) |>
  arrange(Chemical)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>      id Chemical Concentration  TCLP
#>   <int> <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 A                    1   0.1
#> 2     2 A                    2   0.2
#> 3     1 B                   10  10.1
#> 4     2 B                   20  20.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly fast and useful response!

I've gone with the pivot option as I can make it more generic (I'm sure the bind can too but I'm less familiar with that - will look into it more).

For my script I moved the `mutate(id...)` line down one because I tweaked the renaming as I will have variable chemical names to work with. My version looks like:

```
df <- df |>
  rename_with(.cols = !starts_with("TCLP_"), .fn = ~ paste0("Concentration_", .x, "")) |>
  mutate(id = 1:n())|>
  pivot_longer(-id) |>
  separate(name, c("type", "Chemical"), fill = "left") |>
  replace_na(list(type = "Concentration"))  |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(type),
              values_from = value) |>
  arrange(Chemical)
```